# Edit one component and display in two tabsheets at the same time

Tags: delphi

Edit one component with only one Name. But it can be shown in two or more places in the form at the same time. (Say shown in two tabsheets)

So the component shown in different places, changing in synchrony.

Comment: If it's common for many tabs, put it out of the page control. Otherwise you would need to re-parent it. Or keep it *floating over* the page control which would be ugly way.

Comment: There are lots of different options available. One very good option is to have two distinct controls, but bind them to the same data. Perhaps your real problem is that you have coupled the UI to the app logic in a fashion that constrains you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LiveBindings for this. For this purpose you will not have to type even a line of code. Just use LiveBindings Designer.

```
 object LinkControlToPropertyCaption: TLinkControlToProperty
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      Control = Edit1
      Track = True
      Component = Label1
      ComponentProperty = 'Caption'
    end
```

Such link will update the `Caption` of `Lqbel1`. You can also call `BindingsList1.Notify();` function if you need to update the property at some other moment (like when the user is typing text in the Edit1).

Answer (score 0):

In your tab example:

Change the TEdit parent property to the new tab when you switch tabs. Maybe you have to adjust position as well.

When visible at two locations at the same time, you *need* two components. 
Write one common OnChange event handler, if `Sender=TEdit1` update TEdit2.Text from TEdit1.Text, and vice versa.